# AVI Videos not working with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, video

Am trying to play stream video using, 
AVPlayerViewController, all other extensions works fine"3GP MP4 ... ", but  ".avi" the video start with blank screen.

```
  if let videoURL = URL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.avi"){
                        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

                        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

                        playerViewController.player = player

                        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                            playerViewController.player!.play()
                        } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading AVPlayer [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer?language=objc)

> An AVPlayer is a controller object used to manage the playback and timing of a media asset. You can use an AVPlayer to play local and remote file-based media, such as **QuickTime** movies and MP3 audio files

Therefore the video format should be supported by **QuickTime**

and currently the supported formats by **QuickTime** list 
doesn't contain  `.avi`

therefore a proper solution for this is to use a custom video player.